# how to write the output of a process run using execl to a file in c

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a c program in which it calls a process using execl() function. I get the output of the process along with my c program output. I need to store the output of the process called using execl() to a file. I know programming basics and also file input and output.

Here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
main()
{
printf("\nDisplaying output of ifconfig\n");
execl("/sbin/ifconfig","ifconfig",NULL);
}
```

Output:

```
Displaying output of ifconfig

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:a1:88:21  
      ...........

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      ........
```

I need to store the output of ifconfig in the file. How can i do it?

Comment: you can use `pipes` if you want to get the ouput of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) to run the program instead of calling `execl`, and read the out and write it to a file. Or use the [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) function, which invokes a shell and therefore can contain full shell redirection.

Or open the file using [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and then use [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) to redirect it to `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Actually, using the `exec` functions like that is highly unusual. Normally you create a new process and call `exec` in the child process.

---

Using `open` and `dup2` is what I suggest in this case:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

...

/* Open the file for writing (create it if it doesn't exist) */
int fd = open("/path/to/file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP);

/* Make the standard output refer to the newly opened file */
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

/* Now we don't need the file descriptor returned by `open`, so close it */
close(fd);

/* Execute the program */
execl("/sbin/ifconfig","ifconfig",NULL);
```

**Note:** I do not have any kind of error handling in the above code, which you should have.

Comment: Can you elaborate it please?

Comment: @DDR For `popen` the reference contain a simple example, calling `system` is the same as doing e.g. `/bin/sh -c ...` in a shell. For the `open`/`dup2` combination, you open your file, then tell the system that the standard output is this file, before calling `execl`, then it will use that file as standard output.

Comment: I am new to the topic can u just show me an example using popen and system

Comment: @DDR Using `system` is very easy, just to e.g. `system(""/sbin/ifconfig > /path/to/file");`, just like you would call the command in a normal shell with output redirection. Using `popen` is a little bit more advance, as you then have to manually read the output from the command and write to the file manually as well (see [the answer from user1940987](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19732963/440558)). I'll update my answer with the `open`/`dup2` way.

Answer (score 2):

```
 /* Open the command for reading. */
      fp = popen("COMMAND", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to run command\n" );
                    exit;
        }

          /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
          while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fp) != NULL) {
                  printf("buffer = %s", buffer);
            }

            /* close */
            pclose(fp);
```